# How can I redirect standard error with [error] head?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I understand how to output standard error to a log file in shell.

```
BACKUP_DIR="/home/backup/"
BACKUP_LOG="/home/backup.log"
echo "backup start" >>$BACKUP_LOG 2>&1
mkdir $BACKUP_DIR >>$BACKUP_LOG 2>&1
```

When mkdir command fails, i get the message: `no such file or directory`

Is there a way to change the error message to something like: `[error] no such file or directory`?

I want to prepend the text`[error]` to the front of the error message.

Comment: When you do this you lose the guarantee that your logs will remain in their original order -- that guarantee only exists when stdout and stderr are two copies of the same file descriptor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's something to try:

```
mkdir $BACKUP_DIR 2> >(sed $'s,.*,[error] &,'>>$BACKUP_LOG)
```

Adapted from: https://serverfault.com/a/502019/506625.

Tested using

```
BACKUP_DIR="a/b/c"
BACKUP_LOG="junk.log"

mkdir $BACKUP_DIR 2> >(sed $'s,.*,[error] &,'>>$BACKUP_LOG)
```

and junk.log shows

```
[error] mkdir: cannot create directory ‘a/b/c’: No such file or directory
```

---

Also works with command grouping (I'm probably not understanding comment though):

```
TESTFILE1="test1.txt" ; TESTFILE2="test2.txt" ;
echo "Test1" >$TESTFILE1

# make sure 2nd file doesn't exist and remove test log
rm -f $TESTFILE2 ; rm -f $BACKUP_LOG

# Command grouping ; 1st command OK ; 2nd command error
{ cat $TESTFILE1 ; cat $TESTFILE2 ; } 2> >(sed $'s,.*,[error] &,'>>$BACKUP_LOG);
```

and output

```
$ { cat $TESTFILE1 ; cat $TESTFILE2 ; } 2> >(sed $'s,.*,[error] &,'>>$BACKUP_LOG);
Test1

$ cat junk.log
[error] cat: test2.txt: No such file or directory
```

Comment: ths your answer. i have an other question. how can i output of stderr with [error] when i output of multiple commands to one file by {}; like` { mkdir $BACKUP_DIR; rm $BACKUP_DIR;} 2> >(sed $'s,.*,[error] &,'>>$BACKUP_LOG)` ?     but its happened error.

Comment: [syntax error near unexpected token `<' ]happened, i just copy your [2> >(sed $'s,.*,[error] &,'>>$BACKUP_LOG)] , i do not know why i can not run this command.

Comment: You have square brackets "[" "]" ... why?  It is not in the provided sample code.

Comment: sorry, i do not have square brackets "[" "]" in my code, just  2> >(sed $'s,.*,[error] &,'>>$BACKUP_LOG)

Answer (score 0):

File redirection syntax in the shell is flexible, but perhaps a bit obscure.  To add headers to both stdout and stderr streams, you can do things like:

```
{ { cmd | sed -e 's/^/[stdout] /' >&3; } 2>&1 | sed -e 's/^/[stderr] /' >&2; } 3>&1
```

That will add "[stdout] " to the beginning of each line of stdout, and "[stderr] " to the beginning of each line of stderr.  To redirect to files, you need to make sure you do the redirections in the correct order.  For example:

```
{ { cmd | sed -e 's/^/[stdout] /' >&3; } 2>&1 | sed -e 's/^/[stderr] /' >&2; } >"$BACKUP_OUT" 2>"$BACKUP_ERR" 3>&1
```

The easiest way to do multiple commands is probably to simply define them in a function named `cmd` and continue using exactly the same syntax as above.  Of course, you can also add newlines and whitespace to make this more readable, or refactor with some functions. eg:

```
#!/bin/sh

BACKUP_DIR="$HOME/backup/"
BACKUP_OUT="$BACKUP_DIR/out"
BACKUP_ERR="$BACKUP_DIR/err"

cmd() {
        echo do one thing well
        echo do this poorly >&5
        echo three
}

{ {
        cmd \
        | sed -e 's/^/[stdout] /' >&3; } 2>&1 |
        sed -e 's/^/[stderr] /' >&2; } >"$BACKUP_OUT" 2>"$BACKUP_ERR" 3>&1
```

The new-fangled process substitution is certainly cleaner syntax, but will not work in many shells (eg, it is a "bashism").